# change fragment from another Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two activity **A, B**

**A** has **A1, A2, A3** fragment

I am opening **B** Activity as a Dialog on **A** activity

So Activity **A** -------> Open Dialog (Activity **B**)

---

### Now from Activity B, I want to change A's fragment

For Example B has three Button B1,B2 and B3

When I click on B1, dialog will dismiss and A1 fragment will load

when I click on B2, dialog will dismiss and A2 fragment will load

when I click on B3, dialog will dismiss and A3 fragment will load

I have no idea how to handle this, is any way I can handle please suggest me

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could simply start your Activity B by calling `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` from Activity A. When a button gets clicked in Activity B you save the result in `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` and `finish()` Activity B. Activity A now receives the info of the pressed button in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. From there you can make your FragmentTransactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frederik Schweiger +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The first way is startActivityForResult() method in Activity class. In your ActivityA, you would do something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE, bundle);
```

And then in your onclicklistener of button B1 of ActivityB,

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
....
setResult(RESULT_A1);
finish();
...
});
```

And then back to ActivityA:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_A1) {
             // Call Fragment manager and replace current fragment with fragment A1
         }
     }
 }
```

You can do similar things to button b2 b3 and fragment a2 a3

Read more: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)